# Compiling a simple java program with javac

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I need some help with compiling a simple java program using javac.

So I have these 2 files that were given to me by my teacher:

Robot.java

```
class Robot {

  String name;
  int numLegs;
  float powerLevel;

  Robot(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    numLegs = 2;
    powerLevel = 2.0f;
  }

  Robot() {
    this(Standard Model);
  }

  void talk(String phrase) {
    if (powerLevel = 1.0f) {
      System.out.println(name +  says  + phrase);
      powerLevel -= 1.0f;
    } else {
      System.out.println(name +  is too weak to talk.);
    }
  }

  void charge(float amount) {
    System.out.println(name +  charges.);
    powerLevel = powerLevel + amount;
  }
}
```

RobotWorld.java

```
class RobotWorld {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Robot c3po = new Robot("C3PO");
    c3po.talk("'Hello, Java!'");   
  }

}
```

When I try to compile it by typing "javac RobotWorld.java" into my command prompt, it just returns a bunch of errors. How can I fix this? I have JDK 8 installed.

[image]

Comment: Looks to me your just missing a bunch of "" around strings

Comment: And `=` instead of `==`, and an invalid constructor. Was your assignment to fix the errors? Since it clearly contains incorrect syntax.

Comment: powerLevel == 1.0f use 2 = signs

Comment: put double quotes around Standard Model so this("Standard Model");

Comment: I think the purpose of the assignment was for you to figure out what is wrong with the program instead of asking for help here on SO

Comment: This was ment to be example code so I could familiarize myself with compiling java programs, I dont think it was supposed to contain errors so thats weird.

Comment: "Compiling" Java code can also mean debugging Java code

Comment: Also, if you use an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans - it would have let you know where all the problems were - but that would have been cheating if you werent supposed to use one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like all of the double quote characters were removed. I also added another equal sign after "powerLevel =". Try this:

```
class Robot {

    String name;
    int numLegs;
    float powerLevel;

    Robot(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        numLegs = 2;
        powerLevel = 2.0f;
    }

    Robot() {
        this("Standard Model");
    }

    void talk(String phrase) {
        if (powerLevel == 1.0f) {
            System.out.println(name + " says " + phrase);
            powerLevel -= 1.0f;
        } else {
            System.out.println(name + " is too weak to talk.");
        }
    }

    void charge(float amount) {
        System.out.println(name + "charges.");
        powerLevel = powerLevel + amount;
    }
}
```

The program output is: C3PO is too weak to talk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're missing double quotes "" for strings. 
Also, what does Standard Model represent?

It looks like you're intending for your default constructor to call the constructor with parameters, with a robot name of "Standard Model"?

Comment: Looks like Standard Model is another String without quotes.

Comment: Putting the "" around the strings fixed it. Thanks a lot.